# Why I can't catch exception?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

```
try {
  final result = await http.get(pingUrl)
    .catchError((e) => print(e));
  return result;
} catch (e) {
  print(e)
}
```

but I got this:
[image]

Why I can't handle exception here in catch block?

Answer (score 1):

No, because you are catching in Future.

You shouldn't cath in future:

```dart
try {
  final result = await http.get(pingUrl);
    // .catchError((e) => print(e)); <- removed
  return result;
} catch (e) {
  print(e)
}
```

Or throw again in catchError:

```dart
try {
  final result = await http.get(pingUrl)
    .catchError((e) {
       print(e);
       throw foo;
    });

  return result;
} catch (e) {
  print(e)
}
```

I prefer the first option.